# Curl command correct usage

Tags: post, curl, basic-authentication

I am trying to request an authentication token from a service using basic auth, Here is how I build  the curl command

```
curl -H "Authorization:Basic <base64 encoding user:pass>=" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "grant_type=basic" http://auth.mydomain.com/v1/oauth2/token
```

This returns a 404, I have tried to check if the api exists by using the follwong

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://auth.mydomain.com/v1/oauth2/token
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2016 19:56:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 62
Connection: keep-alive
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use the cURL `-u` option to specify `<username>:<password` in cleartext rather than base64-encoding it yourself directly in to an Authorization header.

Furthermore it looks like you're constructing an OAuth 2.0 token request, but there's no such thing in the specification as an `basic` grant type.

Comment: Hi Hans, I have provided the 'grant_type=basic" in the body of the request using the -d option. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Actually that did the tric, changing it to -u "user:pass". thanks so much!!